# Issue of data posting in GSM over the GPRS from when use Different service provider

Tags: gsm, at-commands, gprs, website, internet

I'm using Telit's HE910 GSM Modem To Post The data on web-server.
so i'm using different company service provider SIM Card to test the data posting from different service provider.
In this case when i'm using Vodafone IN SIM card then Data Post Successfully on Web-server. when i'm using different service provide like , idea ,airtel which have also INTERNET PACK activated but not posting the data on web-server.

with this post i have attached different service provider at command and its response log.

---

VODAFONE SIM LOG

/* This Log Is Generating Using Vodafone SIM Card  /*
 /* Data Posted Successfully /*

```
ATE0

OK
AT

OK
AT&K0

OK
AT+CFUN=5

OK
AT+CMEE=2

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,1

OK
AT#SPN

#SPN: Vodafone IN

OK
www
AT#NITZ=1,0

OK
AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "16/11/19,17:29:41"

OK
Time: 17:29:41 , Date: 19/11/16
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","www"

OK
AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.xyz.com",80,0,,,0,120,1

OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 19,0

OK
AT#SGACT=1,0

OK
AT#SGACT=1,1

#SGACT: 10.64.12.73

OK
AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/local/login?email=xyz@gmail.com&password=*****"

OK
AT#HTTPRCV=0
 eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3d3dy56ZW52dXMuY29tXC9zbWFydGZhcm1cL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDc5NTU2Nzg1LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk1OTI3ODUsIm5iZiI6MTQ3OTU1Njc4NSwianRpIjoiYTFhNmJlYTYzYTU2OWIxZWE3Y2ZmOWM3MjcyMmJjMWUifQ.powKjMIXi_PcYwlrC7Ewk6VsiIQOiV2tVfBhS121E9Q

AT#SD=1,0,80,"www.xyz.com"

CONNECT
GET http://xyz.com/local/postdata?master_mac=MSGJC20500LZN&slave_mac=NULL&ax=3583&ay=-1&az=-16630&mx=3&my=4&mz=26&gx=666&gy=43&gz=-54&humidity=99&latitude=00.0000&longitude=00.0000&temperature=29&light=27&combined_moisture_ph=01000100&nutrition=10&battery=35&soil_temp=116&date_time=1911-1729&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3d3dy56ZW52dXMuY29tXC9zbWFydGZhcm1cL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDc5NTU2Nzg1LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk1OTI3ODUsIm5iZiI6MTQ3OTU1Njc4NSwianRpIjoiYTFhNmJlYTYzYTU2OWIxZWE3Y2ZmOWM3MjcyMmJjMWUifQ.powKjMIXi_PcYwlrC7Ewk6VsiIQOiV2tVfBhS121E9Q HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 11:59:53 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1b0
{"user_id":2,"master_mac":"MSGJC20500LZN","slave_mac":"NULL","ax":"3583","ay":"-1","az":"-16630","mx":"3","my":"4","mz":"26","gx":"666","gy":"43","gz":"-54","humidity":"99","latitude":"72.5942","longitude":"23.1039","nutrition":"10","temperature":"29","light":"27","battery":"35","soil_temp":"116","ph":4,"moisture":4,"date_time":"2016-11-19 17:29:00","updated_at":"2016-11-19 17:29:54","created_at":"2016-11-19 17:29:54","id":1847}
0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2016 11:59:53 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

---

IDEA SIM LOG

/* This Log Is Generating Using Idea SIM Card  /*
 /* Data NOT Posted /*

```
ATE0

OK
AT

OK
AT&K0

OK
AT+CFUN=5

OK
AT+CMEE=2

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,1

OK
AT#SPN

#SPN: Idea

OK
imis
AT#NITZ=1,0

OK
AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "16/11/19,17:46:18"

OK
Time: 17:46:18 , Date: 19/11/16
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","imis"

OK
AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.xyz.com",80,0,,,0,120,1

OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 15,3

OK
AT#SGACT=1,0

OK
AT#SGACT=1,1

#SGACT: 10.120.51.157

OK
AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/local/login?email=xyz@gmail.com&password=*****"

+CME ERROR: can not resolve DN

AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/local/login?email=xyz@gmail.com&password=*****"

+CME ERROR: can not resolve DN
```

---

AIRTEL SIM LOG

/* This Log Is Generating Using AIRTEL SIM Card  /*
 /* Data NOT Posted  /*

```
ATE0

OK
AT

OK
AT&K0

OK
AT+CFUN=5

OK
AT+CMEE=2

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,1


AT#SPN

#SPN: airtel

OK
airtelgprs.com
AT#NITZ=1,0

OK
AT+CCLK?

+CCLK: "16/11/19,17:38:37"

OK
Time: 17:38:37 , Date: 19/11/16
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"

OK
AT#HTTPCFG=0,"www.xyz.com",80,0,,,0,120,1

OK
SN:25 AT+CSQ
SN:26 
+CSQ: 13,3

OK
AT#SGACT=1,0

OK
AT#SGACT=1,1

#SGACT: 100.77.200.1

OK
AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/local/login?email=xyz@gmail.com&password=*****"

OK
 AT#HTTPRCV=0
 eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3d3dy56ZW52dXMuY29tXC9zbWFydGZhcm1cL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDc5NTU3MzI0LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk1OTMzMjQsIm5iZiI6MTQ3OTU1NzMyNCwianRpIjoiMTRjZWU1N2JmZmFmNWYwMjFmMzg3ZWNlYTZhZTQzYTIifQ.Np822FKzXVe9Lc5EU6_NchHyqABU3X2MgZXqFjNDUxg

AT#SD=1,0,80,"www.xyz.com"

CONNECT

 GET http://xyz.com/local/postdata?master_mac=MSGJC20500LZN&slave_mac=NULL&ax=3275&ay=547&az=-16807&mx=5&my=-8&mz=6&gx=737&gy=104&gz=-1&humidity=55&latitude=00.0000&longitude=00.0000&temperature=30&light=25&combined_moisture_ph=01000100&nutrition=10&battery=35&soil_temp=94&date_time=0000-0000&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3d3dy56ZW52dXMuY29tXC9zbWFydGZhcm1cL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNDc5NTU3MzI0LCJleHAiOjE0Nzk1OTMzMjQsIm5iZiI6MTQ3OTU1NzMyNCwianRpIjoiMTRjZWU1N2JmZmFmNWYwMjFmMzg3ZWNlYTZhZTQzYTIifQ.Np822FKzXVe9Lc5EU6_NchHyqABU3X2MgZXqFjNDUxg HTTP/1.1


NO CARRIER
```

---

Comment: Hello Bence , 
Thanks for Adding my question.
I am Beginner in community.

Comment: i have found different solution to resolve that using vodafone sim card data posting successfully. when using airtel simcard send data using HTTP/1.1.
when i'm sending data like HTTP/1.1\r\n but data modified in controller and Send Data too gsm is HTTP1.1\r\r\n. 
in idea sim card internet connection is not established properly. and disconnect automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is very different from my thinking actually in this GSM module UART interfacing used. So, whenever I want to communicate to GSM send the command over UART to GSM. 
there is some unexpected behavior I have found when I'm sending data like **HTTP/1.1\r\n** but data modified in the controller and Send Data to GSM is **HTTP1.1\r\r\n\n**. in idea sim card.